# What limits system clock in MCU? How high can I go?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator, dsp

I'd like to produce PWM outputs at f_PWM ~= 100kHz and I'd like to connect the ADC to sample
at least once during each high-time interval of the PWM output.

Everything in my configuration of these peripherals seems to tie back to the system clock (F_CY) which I get from an external resonator (and then goes through a PLL and then I get my clock).  So, without having to move to specialized IC's, I'm trying to understand how fast I can go?

Is it just the limit of how nice of a resonator I can buy?  I've never used a resonator beyond 20MHz.

I know things eventually are limited by parasitic capacitances etc, but how do I find my limit practically?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend crystals or crystal oscillators at 10MHz+. Resonators tend to drift a bit too much.

Comment: The maximum recommended clock frequency for your processor will be given in its datasheet.

Comment: What are you trying to drive that you need 100kHz+ PWM? Just curious.

Comment: Possibly audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are limited by the design and silicon in the MCU. The datasheet will tell you how high the chip is designed to run at, and you could try pushing it past that, but at that point, you are "overclocking" it. Any extra speed you get is a bonus, but has the risk of not being stable.

Comment: Wow, specially "augmented" chips, so is this an "implant"?

Comment: @rawbrawb only if you're okay with no anesthesia. Not approved for surgery and implantation.